# Ansible template variable using inventory groups

Tags: deployment, ansible

I am trying to make a template for repcached memcached.
this contains a line such as below

```
OPTIONS="-x 192.168.XXX.XXX -X 11212"
```

Where 192.168.XXX.XXX is one of 2 entries in an inventory group.

Basically in a 2 node setup the node needs to be configured to point to the other node in its inventory group.

I have been struggling with jinja2 templates trying to get it to use (inventory_group - inventory_host) as this would give me the required value however i seem to be unable to find a syntax that works.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with lists might take you quite far. I'm not sure this is the right way to go. Notably, the `-` operator doesn't *remove an item from a list* (while, interestingly, `+` can concat lists, and thus add items to a list).

This being said, I suggest you take care of this in your template, like this (assuming the group is called repcached) :

```
{% for h in groups['repcached'] -%}
{% if h != inventory_hostname %}
OPTIONS="-x {{ hostvars[h]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}  -X 11212"
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You might want to adjust the `['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']` part if you want to get the IP address from another source (see `ansible repcached -m setup` output to see available choices).

Of course, this only works if there are only TWO servers in the `repcached` group. You could add a safeguard by bailing out in your playbook if the item count in the group is not 2.